# Error "Attempt to protect stack guard pages failed"

Tags: python, jvm, conda, pyjnius

I am trying to use the PyJnius library to interact with JVM in Python. However, when I import jnius, I get the following warning:

```
>>> import jnius
[0.002s][warning][os,thread] Attempt to protect stack guard pages failed (0x000000016d1f0000-0x000000016d1fc000).
[0.002s][warning][os,thread] Attempt to deallocate stack guard pages failed.
```

However, subsequent usage seems to be fine:

```
>>> Stack = autoclass('java.util.Stack')
>>> stack = Stack()
>>> stack.push("world")
'world'
>>> print(stack.pop())
world
```

I was wondering if this is something I should be worried about or can safely ignore?

I am working in a conda environment, and the details of my environment are:

- device: M2 macbook
- Miniconda for m1 MacOS
- Python 3.8.16
- Pyjnius 1.4.2
- Java OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM JBR-11.0.13.7-1751.21-jcef

I tried to reinstall openjdk, but that did not help.

Comment: The java.util.Stack class has nothing to do with the OS thread stack.

Comment: Yeah but I got the error when importing the jnius library, and autoclass is a method in jnius.